# EF generic method overloading

Tags: c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

I'd like make possible a generic method overload.
Since I need to create an `ObjectSet<..>` without knowing the generic type contained in, I wold build something like this:

```
public IQueryable<T> MyMethod<T>() where T : class, (IMyFirst || IMySecond) //notice the syntax..!
{
  if(typeOf(T) is IMyFirst..
  else ...
}
```

How can I reach my purpose..?

#### Update:

@BrokenGlass wrote:

> This type of constraint is not possible in C# - you could however constrain to IFoo and have IMyFirst and IMySecond both implement IFoo.

But that suggestion is not applicable, please see this:

```
interface1 { property1 {..}}
interface2 { property2 {..}}
interfaceIFoo : interface1, interface2 { }
```

by any method:

```
MyWrapper.Retrieve<EntityProduct>(myObjContext); //error-> EntityProduct implements interface1 only!!
```

by other any method:

```
MyWrapper.Retrieve<EntityOrder>(myObjContext); //error-> EntityOrder implements interface2 only!!
```

and here:

```
public static IQueryable<T> Retrieve<T>(ObjectContext context) where T :class, interfaceIFoo    
{
var query = context.CreateObjectSet<T>().AsQueryable();
//...
```

Comment: You got your interfaces swapped from my example - interface1 should implement IFoo, not the other way round.

Comment: ok, but inside my method I cannot use lamba expression!! that's because InterfaceIfoo is declarative only, not any field exists in its.

Answer (score 0):

This type of constraint is not possible in C# - you could however constrain to `IFoo` and have `IMyFirst` and `IMySecond` both implement `IFoo`.

If you can live with dependencies on Entity Framework you could alternatively also use `EntityObject`

Comment: Entity object? Well, I can use it, but how so..?

Answer (score 0):

A disjunctive generic constraint doesn't really make sense.  Those constraints provide compile-time information to the method, so there's not much point in constraints that result in an ambiguous type at compile time.  For instance, if your method is just going to resort to run-time type checking, you might as well just do this:

```
public IQueryable<T> MyMethod<T>() where T : class
{
    if (typeOf(T) is IMyFirst) ...
    else ...
}
```

If you feel you need the type checking on input and a pseudo-abstraction, perhaps extension methods that happen to be identically named would suffice:

```
public static IQueryable<IMyFirst> MyMethod(this IMyFirst input)
{
    return ...
}

public static IQueryable<IMySecond> MyMethod(this IMySecond input)
{
    return ...
}
```